# XTS does not recognize datetime as an appropriate time-based object

Tags: r, xts

I am using R. I have a tibble of values and a datetime index. I want to convert the tibble in an xts.

Here you are sample data and the code I use:

```
Date <- c("2010-01-04" , "2010-01-04")
Time <- c("04:00:00", "06:00:00")
value <- c(1, 2)          
df <- as_tibble(value) %>% add_column(Date = Date, Time = Time)
df <- df %>% mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

library(xts)
dfxts <- as.xts(df[,1], order.by=df[,4])
```

Nevertheless, I get the following error:

```
Error in xts(x, order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency, ...) : 
    order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

Any idea what is driving this? Datetime should be an appropriate time-based object... Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `order_by` must be a vector. When you extract from a `tbl_df` using `foo[,bar]` the class of the returned object is not a vector, it is a `tbl_df`. Use `df[[4]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-examine each step and check what you are getting. I actually find that easiest to do in *one* container. You could use `tbl`, I happen to like `data.frame`.

So let's first build a `data.frame` from your data:

```
R> Date <- c("2010-01-04" , "2010-01-04")
R> Time <- c("04:00:00", "06:00:00")
R> value <- c(1, 2)
R> df <- data.frame(Date=Date, Time=Time, value=value)
R> df
        Date     Time value
1 2010-01-04 04:00:00     1
2 2010-01-04 06:00:00     2
R>
```

Let's then collate and parse the date and time info and check it:

```
R> df[,"pt"] <- as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time))
R> df
        Date     Time value                  pt
1 2010-01-04 04:00:00     1 2010-01-04 04:00:00
2 2010-01-04 06:00:00     2 2010-01-04 06:00:00
R>
```

After that it is just a matter of calling `xts` with the correct components:

```
R> x <- xts(df[,"value"], order.by=df[,"pt"])
R> x
                    [,1]
2010-01-04 04:00:00    1
2010-01-04 06:00:00    2
R>
```

*Edit* Or you could it all in one step *without any other package* but forgoing to ability to step through intermediate steps:

```
R> x2 <- xts(value, order.by=as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time)))
R> x2
                    V1
2010-01-04 04:00:00  1
2010-01-04 06:00:00  2
R> all.equal(x, x2)
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Comment: To be clear, the OP's data is a `tbl_df` object, not a `data.frame`. Your example only works because `base::[.data.frame` works differently than `tibble:::[.tbl_df`. `[.data.frame` coerces the the returned object to a vector if only one variable in a `data.frame` is extracted. This is not the behavior of `[.tbl_df`.

Comment: The OP requested a method to convert a tibble to an xts object.

Comment: Just for _your_ education I added an option to do it all from the _three initial vectors_.  Look, Ma, no `data.frame` and no `tbl`.  Must be magic....

Comment: Please re-read the title.  Where does it say `tbl`?  In my reading OP rushed to using a `tbl` _and then got lost because of using one_.  I show two alternatives.  Maybe we should let the OP decide for us what he/she wanted.

Comment: Look, I don't really want to get into it with you. OP states in their post "I have a tibble of values and a datetime index." Your answers are obviously correct but do not address OP's situation or questions. The data is just sample data.

Comment: You are still wrong. OP starts from three base vectors.  Which, as one may, are then glued into a tibble _in the fourth step_.  You can repeat it a dozen more times but it _did not start with a tbl_.  All we see is that using a tbl results in error.  You show one fix, I show two others.  Only you have the classic move of downvoting the other.  You be you.