# R xts does not recognize my POSIXct dates

Tags: r, dataframe, xts, posixct

I have a dataframe (data_frame) with two columns.

```
> head(data_frame)
                  Date Rainfall
1 1992-01-06 14:00:00      0.3
2 1992-01-06 15:00:00      0.2
3 1992-01-06 16:00:00      0.3
4 1992-01-06 18:00:00      0.1
5 1992-01-06 19:00:00      0.3
6 1992-01-06 20:00:00      0.8
```

Date is of class `POSIXct`. Rainfall is `numeric`.

```
> class(data_frame$Date)
[1] "POSIXct"
```

When I try to create a time series using `xts`, I get this error:

```
> time_series = xts(data_frame$Rainfall, order.by = data_frame$Date)
```

> Error in xts(data_frame$Rainfall, order.by = data_frame$Date) :
> order.by requires an appropriate time-based object

`xts` should be able to handle `POSIXct`. I went through a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447398/xts-does-not-recognize-datetime-as-an-appropriate-time-based-object), where the solution was to convert date into the above format. Looking at those answers, my code should work. I can't figure out why it is not.

reproducible example:

```
head_data_frame = structure(list(
  Date = structure(
    c(
      694659600,
      694663200,
      694666800,
      694674000,
      694677600,
      694681200
    ),
    class = "POSIXct"
  ),
  Rainfall = c(0.3,
               0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8)
),
row.names = c(NA, 6L),
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you have another package loaded which masks the `xts` function? Try `time_series 
 <- xts::xts(data_frame$Rainfall, order.by = data_frame$Date)`

Comment: Nah same errors

Comment: Then please provide a reproducible example with `dput(head(data_frame))`

Comment: @RonakShah I've edited the question to include it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the question has been closed now. You may ask a new question if the linked post doesn't answer your question.

Comment: The question author subsequently asked the question again and received and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69360322/xts-function-doesnt-consider-my-posixct-dates-as-an-appropriate-time-based-obje